# Render GUI from React component functions

Tags: component, react

I'm not sure if this is the right way to build React components.

I have a component with several buttons that call different functions in the component. In some of the functions I need to display some extra GUI (inputs, etc.). In vanilla JS I could just do this by creating the elements (`document.createElement….`) and add them to the DOM/remove them once they're not needed any more.

However in React I can't find a way to do this (of course, I could break out of the "React prison" and just create what I need and add it manually to the DOM).

I have solved this in a way I don't like today. I'm creating everything I need in the render function and hide or show it based on some props/session state variable.

I'm trying to create something like modal dialogs and I don't want to navigate to some other component.

What would be the correct way to do this?